# How to move chapter number in classicthesis class

Tags: positioning, numbering, chapters, classicthesis

I am using [`classicthesis`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/) for my thesis. In each chapter LaTeX puts its number, but I need to move it.

Here you have an screenshot example, in this image I wish to move "4" number to the left.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 10):

[`classicthesis`](http://ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) sets the chapter number as a `\marginpar` if you *don't* use the `linedheaders` package option. Regardless, setting of the chapter heading is done with the aid of [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). From the actual [`classicthesis.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty), you'll see:

```
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@linedheaders}}%
{% lines above and below, number right
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%             
    {\relax}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}%
    {\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
}{% something like Bringhurst  
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\relax}{\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{0pt}%
    {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]% 
}
```

The former `\titleformat` corresponds to the `linedheaders` package option, while the latter is without. You could provide your own updated version:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\relax}{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{0pt}%
  {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
```

I've placed the chapter number in a box of width `\linewidth`, `r`ight-aligned.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{classicthesis,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{classicthesis,lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\relax}{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{0pt}%
  {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Perhaps, in a more general setting, any of the adjustments possible and/presented in the [`titlesec` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) would work, many of which you'll [find on this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/titlesec+chapters).