# Remove Marginpar from Classicthesis 4.1

Tags: positioning, marginpar, classicthesis

I am searching for a safe method to remove the `\marginpar` feature in [classicthesis](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/). My corrector would rather have the text use the whole page. I am not that firm in LaTeX, so I tried to simply remove all occurrences/command references, but this only messes with the layout of the margin-notes.

I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84698/how-to-move-chapter-number-in-classicthesis-class), which moves the chapter number into the title.

I would appreciate the help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) No need to add thanks, the preferred way to acknowledge help is to upvote answers.

Answer (score 6):

You should try resisting the wish of your corrector. But if you can't, here's a way:

```
\documentclass[
  twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,
  footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
  BCOR=10mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt,
]{scrbook}


\usepackage[linedheaders]{classicthesis}

%%% Change the text block area to add also the margin space
\areaset[current]{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}{\textheight}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter title}

\section{A section}

\kant


\end{document}
```

The `kantlipsum` package is just to provide mock text.

[image]

Comment: can you send me a black template with your modifications? I am new to Lyx, but managed to type some chapters using Lyx. My professor wants me to use the full paper.